# Odoo 10 - Pass context to a wizard called by a button inside FormView.buttons template

Tags: javascript, odoo

I added a new button next to the create one in the FormView.

```
<t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.o_form_button_create" t-operation="after">
        <t t-if="widget.fields_view.name == 'site.form'">
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm oe_create_customer_button_form">
                Create Customer Site
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

---

I linked an action to it to open a wizard form.

Now I would pass values from the record displayed in the form at the moment of the wizard call, but I'm having some trouble.
It holds only the reference of the first record opened, so when I call the wizard from another record it will display data from the first one.

```
instance.web.FormView.include({
    render_buttons: function() {
        var self = this
        this._super.apply(this, arguments)

        // GET BUTTON REFERENCE
        if (this.$buttons) {
            var btn = this.$buttons.find('.oe_create_customer_button_form')
        }
        self.do_query(btn)
    },
    do_query: function(btn) {
        var self = this
        var context = {}

        // QUERY THE MODEL   --   DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY
        // TO PASS PARENT
        new instance.web.Model('broadband.site')
            .query()
            .filter([['id', '=', self.dataset.ids[0]]])
            .first()
            .done(function(res) {
                if(res) {
                    context = {
                        'default_parent_id': res.id
                    }
                }
                self.do_new_button(context, btn)
            })
    },
    do_new_button: function (context, btn) {
        var self = this

        var action = ({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: 'broadband.wizard',
            view_type: 'form',
            view_mode: 'form',
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            target: 'new',
            context: context
        })

        btn.on('click', function() {
            self.do_action(action)
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I overwrote *'load_record'* function to get *'datarecord'* object and use it instead of *'dataset'*.

Here's the code:

```
instance.web.FormView.include({
    is_site: function() {
        if (this.dataset.model && this.dataset.model == 'broadband.site') {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    },
    render_buttons: function() {
        if(this.is_site() && !this.$buttons) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    },
    load_record: function() {
        var self = this

        if(this.is_site()) {
            self._super.apply(this, arguments)
            var btn = self.$buttons.find('.oe_create_customer_button_form')
            btn.hide()
            if(self.datarecord.site_type != 'last_mile') {
                btn.show()
            }
            self.do_query(btn)
        } else {
            self._super.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    },
    do_query: function(btn) {
        var self = this
        var context = {}
        var passed = false

        if(this.is_site()) {

            var site_id = self.datarecord.id

            btn.on('click', function() {
                new instance.web.Model('broadband.site')
                    .query()
                    .filter([['id', '=', site_id]])
                    .first()
                    .then(function(res) {
                        if(res && !passed) {
                            context = {
                                'default_parent_id': res.id
                            }
                            self.do_button_action(context)
                            passed = true
                        }
                    })
            })
        }
    },
    do_button_action: function (context) {
        var self = this

        var action = ({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: 'broadband.wizard',
            view_type: 'form',
            view_mode: 'form',
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            target: 'new',
            context: context
        })

        self.do_action(action)

    }
})
```